# "Can not find subscription" error when create the scheduler in azure portal

Tags: azure, scheduler, azure-webjobs, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I'm getting Can not find subscription error when create the scheduler Job Collection in azure portal.

I am having Owner role Role Based Access Control (RBAC) for resource group(but not have access at subscription level).I am able to create storage accounts but when i try to create scheduler azure throws **Can not find subscription** error with Microsoft.Scheduler namespace.

If i publish as owner of subscription scheduler automatically created for webjobs and i am able to create manually also.

> Is Resource group owner access sufficient to create scheduler in azure portal ?

If yes, Please explain how to create scheduler with resource group owner access.

NOte:I published webjobs from visual studio.Webjobs have been created under webapps .Webapps have been created but scheduler has not been created.

Comment: If you're running in Standard mode or higher, there is a much simpler way that you can do scheduled jobs using a CRON expression defined in a `settings.job` file, rather than an external scheduler service. See the "Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression" section of [this doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

> No.Resource group owner access is not sufficient to create scheduler
>   job collection in azure portal.

From this [microsoft azure article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/scheduler-concepts-terms/) job collection can be created by subscription owner.

Job collection of Scheduler entity hierarchy defined as:

A job collection contains a group of jobs and maintains settings, quotas, and throttles that are shared by jobs within the collection. ***A job collection is created by a subscription owner*** and groups jobs together based on usage or application boundaries. It’s constrained to one region. It also allows the enforcement of quotas to constrain the usage of all jobs in that collection. The quotas include MaxJobs and MaxRecurrence.

But still not sure why only subscription owner allowed to create job collection.

Answer (score 1):

Resource group owners can create job collections. You need to first make sure that the subscription owner has registered the subscription to use the Scheduler service. This is done automatically when the subscription owner creates their first resource of that resource type through the portal or you can do it programmatically via this REST API: [Registering a subscription with a resource provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790548.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean resource owner can create new resource only if subscription  owner created at least one resource?

Comment: It is not required that the subscription owner create the first resource just that the subscription owner registers their subscription with the resource type which can be done programmatically (or via Fiddler/Postman) using the API I referenced above.
As a convenience, when the subscription owner creates the first resource of a particular resource type in the portal, the subscription is automatically registered with the resource type.

Comment: @KevinLam, I can confirm this works. Basicly adding a job collection through the new portal (it didn't work through the old portal for me) and removing this one. I could then call `New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection` and it would succeed. Thanks for the hint, was really helpful :)